# how i can put the background of my navigation transparent?

Tags: react-native, navigation

Do you think it's possible to put the background of my bottom nav transparent without to put the navigation in a position absolute ?

i noticed my app is more responsive without the absolute on my code !

```
 <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarStyle: {
          bottom: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 20 : 10,

          backgroundColor: "#5DC1D3",
          borderRadius: 35,
          height: 90,
        },
      }}>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried in your `tabBarStyle` just making `backgroundColor: 'transparent',`?

Comment: Yes already tried and it's doesn't work